# How do i stop a button from taking up an entire panel?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to add some buttons to the bottom of my GUI, but whenever I add the buttons to the panel, it takes up literally the entire panel. i.e.

```
JPanel PanelForButtons = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel lowPanel = new JPanel();
lowPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
lowPanel.add(PanelForButtons);
mainPanel.add(lowPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
GUI.add(mainPanel);
GUI.setVisible(true);
```

However, one button then takes up the entire PanelForButtons. How do i stop this from happening? thanks

Comment: i don't see any buttons there, you create a JPanel then add another JPanel into it. is this what you meant to do? You can adjust the size of these elements

Comment: set the area of the button..height, width that you can control. You can also change margin and padding...For the panel you can also control these things

Comment: The buttons are added I just didnt include it, I just do a standard                  button1 = new JButton("button1");
        PanelForButtons.add(button1);

Comment: your JPanel is called `lowPanel` yet you are passing in `lowerPanel` in to the `mainPanel`

Comment: fixed that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a BorderLayout for the PanelForButtons JPanel. BorderLayout causes the component to take up the entire space. Use a different layout manager; BoxLayout can work well for this issue.

Comment: that seems to have fixed the issue! thanks very much